# Programmatically add values to Angular 2 NgForm object

Tags: forms, angular

I have a form that works great. It's built with 
`@ViewChild('f') formData: NgForm;` so that I can fully access to each input value.

I submit the form data like this:
`this.postJobService.sendPost(this.formData.value)`

and the object sent is

```
Object {groupDat: Object}
    groupData:Object
        category:"tags"
        city:"Boston"
        description:"Awesome article"
        state:"MA"
        title: "An article title"
        ...
```

Now for many reasons, including unit testing, how do you add new values to `NgForm` and or specifically `formData.value.groupData` object before I submit the form?

Comment: Try model driven form approach to better suit unit testing.

Comment: setValue and patchValue could help https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html#!#set-data